# Buddypress - Add HTML into the User Profile - only first profile group

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I've got 3 profile groups/sections in my Buddypress General profile tab.

I'm trying to add a custom shortcode into the first group, just under the first group.

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'bp_after_profile_loop_content', 'profile_choices_display' );
function profile_choices_display() {
   if ( 1 == bp_get_the_profile_group_id()) { 
     echo do_shortcode( '[user-profile-choices]' );
   }      
}
```

Without the `bp_get_the_profile_group_id()` filter, the shortcode is repeated under each of the 3 groups on that page.

Any ideas how to achieve this so it only shows after the first group?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `bp_get_the_profile_group_id() `?

Comment: I don't, ideally I want to keep that filter, but the code doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook you used is called too late.
Try:

```
add_action( 'bp_after_profile_field_content', 'profile_choices_display' );
function profile_choices_display() {
   if ( 'edit' !== bp_current_action() ) {
       if ( 1 == bp_get_the_profile_group_id()) { 
          echo do_shortcode( '[user-profile-choices]' );
       }
   }      
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! It ads the shortcode just below the first group on the `domain.com/members/user` page which is what I wanted, but it also ads the shortcode into the group edit page `domain.com/members/user/profile/edit/group/1/` . Is there a way to exclude it from showing on this edit page?

Comment: I mean I can probably do it with jQuery, but is there a way to do it directly from that function so it only shows under the first group of fields on the member profile page, but not on the profile edit page?

Comment: See edit re `bp_current_action`.